# get_stylesheet_directory_uri() not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following in the child theme functions.php:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'helloooo');

function helloooo(){
wp_enqueue_script( 'my_js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array('jquery') );
}
```

yet scripts.js is not getting called. I've been at this forever and am at my wits end so any help is greatly appreciated!

Site: http://www.bridgechurchbr.com/

Comment: Have you tried to place the add_action call below your method?  Also have you tried echoing out the get_stylesheet_directory_uri() call to see if it gives the correct path?

Comment: It seems to be loading the script on your site: `/wp-content/themes/daisho-child/js/scripts.js?ver=4.0.1`

Comment: Yeah it started loading right after I posted this. Sorry for that, guys I was just going a bit insane and it's a really poorly coded Themeforest theme that I advised against so it's been doing weird crap.

Comment: No problem, good to hear it's solved.